# Root program of the files

Tags: java, file, file-association

I want to make a program (for Mac it is AppDelete) that deletes all the files related to that program (Java program).

How it is with the file affiliation (what files are from what programs).

Comment: Are you looking to create an uninstaller? For your own app?

Comment: uninstaller for any app , i understood if you drag and drop an app ( on mac ) in trash it will uninstall the app but some files will still be on your hdd , i want to create an app that takes all the files from that program and deletes them ( but also now that you mention it i don`t think delete an app = uninstalling an app )

Comment: @LES What does it mean for a file to be ‘*from*’ a program? What if a file is ‘*from*’ more than one program? How do you indent to list the files that are ’*from*’ a given program?

Comment: all the files that come from a program installation(and files that are created after but just for the wellbeing of that specific program) ! a file that needs all the other files from that particular program to do something ! a file that if you delete it it will not affect the existence of any of the other programs  from your computer

Comment: @LES That sounds like an unsolvable problem, or at least *very* hard. How on earth would one determine whether the deletion of a file affects an application, without ‘test deleting’ it and then running *all* possible operations of the application?! And should this be done for *all* applications and *all* files? And what about files that a user has saved from an application? Should they all be deleted? Should all documents I've written with a word processor be deleted when it's uninstalled? Or all files I've downloaded with a browser?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should search directories for that specific App name, then list all found files and their content that has App name in them and let the user decide what to delete. About the regedit entries, well its dangerous and complicated to play with be at your own risk.